# Set theory questions - Subsets from Zorich Mathematical Analysis I

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am doing a text that my big brother gave me: Mathematical Analysis I - Zorich. This stuff is pretty hard for me, since in class we don't do sets.

I can see why they are true with pictures, but i don't know how to prove them mathematically:

---

$A,B,C\subset M$

**1.a)**    $(A \subset C) \wedge (B \subset C) \Leftrightarrow ((A \cup B) \subset C)$

I can see that if the left is true, the right is true, and if one is false, the other is false.

but what if $A$ exclusively OR $B$ subsets C, then the right is true, but the left is false?

---

**1.b)** $(C\subset A) \wedge (C \subset B) \Leftrightarrow (C\subset (A \cap B))$

This seems obvious, but how to mathematically show it? i can just draw the Venn diagram again, but that is not math?

---

Side question: Do Venn diagrams count as mathematical proofs? Or are they just a tool to clear things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ *exclusively or* $B$ are contained in $C$, then $A\cup B$ is *not* a subset of $C$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $A\subset C$ and $B\not\subset C$. If $A\cup B\subset C$ then $B\subset C$.

I'll give the hint of 1.b): use the definition of intersection
$$A\cap B=\{x:x\in A\land x\in B\}.$$

Let assume $x\in C$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ so...

Comment: is my attempt to solve 1b from your answers advice correct(see second answer)

Comment: @beginner So, your question is using Venn diagrams as mathematical proof is valid?

Comment: that was a secondary question. was my attempt below correct by the way?

Comment: @beginner I think it has some error. $C\subset A$ and $C\subset B$ does not imply $C\subset A\cap B$ directly. But, since if $x\in C$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, so $x\in A\cap B$ by definition of $A\cap B$ so $x\in C\implies x\in A\cap B$ (that is, $C\subset A\cap B$.)

Comment: is that better? thank you, I think i get it now!

Comment: Your modified proof seems correct :)

Comment: thank you very much tetori, you are a great help!

Answer (score 0):

$$(C\subset A) \wedge (C \subset B) \Leftrightarrow (C\subset (A \cap B))$$

Proof:
$$(C\subset A) \wedge (C \subset B) \implies (C\subset (A \cap B))$$
Assume $C\subset A$ and $C\subset B$. This means $\forall x\in C, x\in A$ and $x\in B$. From this we can see that $\forall x\in C,x\in (A\cap B)$. Since this is all $x\in C$, $C\subset A\cap B$.

We must now prove that:$$(C\subset A) \wedge (C \subset B) \Longleftarrow (C\subset (A \cap B))$$

Assume $C\subset (A\cap B)$ hence $\forall x\in C, x\in A\cap B$, since $(A\cap B) \subset A$ and $(A\cap B) \subset B$, $\forall x\in C,x\in A$ and $x\in B$

thus it is proved.